# PHP code works command line but cannot debug

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, xdebug

I'm working with PHP client code that includes a Symfony dom-crawler (added via composer). It works great when run from the command line; however, when debugging it will crash with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/jeff/newproject/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Crawler.php:189
```

I'm using PHP 7.1, Eclipse, Xdebug on Ubuntu. I'm experiencing the same issue with another dependency as well so I suspect it's Eclipse/Xdebug related.

Any ideas where to start looking?

Update: I ensured php-xml is the latest version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.1-xml is already the newest version (7.1.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Make sure that the `xml` extensions are installed/enabled, specifically `php-xml` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux (and OSX) make sure that on eclipse php configuration you checked "Use system default php.ini configuration". Without this files from /etc/php-version/conf.d/*.ini will not be loaded, so also XML will be not available.